# Where are rails script-generated routes stored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using the rails script, I have generated a five column table (ID, title, content, created_at, updated_at) and its relevant views and controllers using the following command:

```
rails generate scaffold Input title:string content:text
```

It also created a few new routes for the creation, the reading, the updating and the deletion of database entries:

```
 inputs GET    /inputs(.:format)           inputs#index
                 POST   /inputs(.:format)           inputs#create
       new_input GET    /inputs/new(.:format)       inputs#new
      edit_input GET    /inputs/:id/edit(.:format)  inputs#edit
           input GET    /inputs/:id(.:format)       inputs#show
                 PUT    /inputs/:id(.:format)       inputs#update
                 DELETE /inputs/:id(.:format)       inputs#destroy
```

But where are these routes stored? They're not in rails' 'routes.rb' file!

Comment: yes they are in `config/routes.rb`  as the line `resources :inputs` (assuming you scaffolded)

Comment: @Doon And in-turn, where are :input's methods coming from?

Comment: `:input` is a symbol. rails uses the symbol to but the routes. you could manually build each one as name routed using `match, get, post`, but this is a shortcut to to build a set of "restful" routes for you

Comment: and which methods the controller methods? the HTTP Verbs?   The route is just a mapping between uri and controller#method. you can define whatever you want using the routing DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `config/routes.rb` file. You will find an entry `resources :inputs`.

This is responsible for creation of these RESTful routes with meaningful path helpers which you see above.

A `resource`, by default, adds seven actions for a model - `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update`, `destroy`, `index`, `show`. All these are triggered with a generic URI and HTTP verb `(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)`

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

More specifically

> resources :photos
>   creates seven different routes in your application, all mapping to the Photos controller: